# Youtube-data API "part" request parameter doesn't accept "player" as the value

Tags: youtube-data-api

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

The link above says I can set the part attribute in the request to be "player". But when I do this, I get a bad response.

My code is below:

```
$("form").on("keyup", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // prepare the request
   if ($('#search').val() === '') {
    $('#results').html("");
   } else {
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 10,
            videoEmbeddable: true,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"
       }); 
       // execute the request
       request.execute(function (response) {
          var results = response.result;
          $("#results").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
              $("#results").append('<span>' + item.player.embedHtml + '</span>');
            });
          });
          resetVideoHeight();

    $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The link your referring is for videos endpoint, but your code using search endpoint. The search endpoint only accept snippet.

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource